# Javascript variable scope for text input to create d3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scope

I'm trying to take user text input (from a text box) and use it to create a d3 graph. I'm struggling with using the entered data-- I'm trying to save it to sessionStorage, and then later use it in the same way I would use json to create the graph.

Some relevant bits of code:

(I've amalgamated logquery() with the parsequery() function.)

```
function parsequery() {                                                                                  

  var query = [];                                                                                    
  var queryoperators = [];                                                                           
  var queryterms = [];                                                                               
  var jsonnodes = '';                                                                                
  var jsonlinks = ''; 

  blah blah blah bits that figure out jsonnodes, jsonlinks from user entered text in text box

jsontext = "{\n\t\"nodes\": [" + jsonnodes + "\n\t]," + "\n\n\t\"links\": [" + jsonlinks + "\n\t]\n}";
sessionStorage.setItem("jsontext", jsontext);                                                      
jsonstring = sessionStorage.getItem("jsontext");

};
```

then later

```
var graph = jsontext;

var link = svg.append("g")                                                                                           
  .attr("class", "links")                                                                                          
  .selectAll("line")                                                                                                 
  .data(graph.links)
```

I get the following error: *Cannot read property 'links' of undefined*

I know the graph creation code works because I've used the contents of the 'jsontext' variable to create a graph successfully. For example, it might be:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "cat"},
    {"id": "dog"}
  ],

"links": [
    {"source": "cat", "target":"cat"},
    {"source": "cat", "target":"dog"},
    {"source": "dog", "target":"cat"},
    {"source": "dog", "target":"dog"}
]
```

}

I imagine this has something to do with the scope of the jsontext variable. I've tried declaring it at the top of the script:

```
var jsontext;
```

or

```
var jsontext = '';
```

or

```
var jsontext = {};
```

but none of these seem to help.

P.S. This is my first SA question, please be nice to me. And feel free to suggest ways to clarify the question, or request more code!

P.P.S. Here is all my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                          <!-- Sets DOCTYPE. -->
<meta charset="utf-8">                                                                                   <!-- Sets charset. -->


<style>                                                                                                  /* Style stuff coming up: */
  .links line {
    /*stroke: #999;*/
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }

  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }                                                                                              
</style>                                                                                                 <!-- Style stuff done. -->

<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>                                                                     <!-- Sets width and height of svg element. -->
<script src="d3.js"></script>                                                                            <!-- Find d3 here. -->

<script>                                                                                                 // Javascript coming up:

var jsontext = '';

function parsequery() {                                                                                  // Function to parse querytext:

      var query = [];                                                                                    // Create array for all query words.
      var queryoperators = [];                                                                           // Create array for query operators.
      var queryterms = [];                                                                               // Create array for query terms.
      var jsonnodes = '';                                                                                // Create a string for json nodes.
      var jsonlinks = '';                                                                                // Create a string for json links.

      var allAND = true;                                                                                 // Create Boolean variable to indicate all AND operators, set to true. 
      var allOR = true;                                                                                  // Create Boolean variable to indicate all OR operators, set to true.      

      var querytext = document.getElementById("querytext").value;                                        // Set querytext variable to (querytext) text from text box.
      document.getElementById("querytoprint").textContent = querytext;                                   // Set querttoprint text to be (querytext) text from text box.    
      query = querytext.split(" ");                                                                      // Create array which is all query words split by spaces.

      for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {                                                           // Iterate through query, pushes words to terms array or operators array:

        if (query[i] == query[i].toUpperCase()) {                                                        // If query[i] is an uppercase term...
            queryoperators.push(query[i]);                                                               // put it in the operators array.
        }                                                                    

        else{                                                                                            // Else...
          queryterms.push(query[i]);                                                                     // put it in the terms array.
        }                                                                    
      }                                                                                                  // Done iterating through query.


      for (var i = 0; i <queryterms.length; i++){                                                                     // Iterate through the terms array. For each term...
        if (i) {(jsonnodes +=(","))};                                                                                 // If past first array value, add a comma to jsonnodes variable.
          jsonnodes += ("\n\t\t{\"id\": \"" + queryterms[i] + "\"}");                                                 // Add term to jsonnodes variable.         
      };

      for (var i = 0; i <queryoperators.length; i++){                                                                 // Iterate through operators array. For each operator... 

        if (queryoperators[i]=="OR"){                                                                                 // If the operator is OR...
          allAND = false;                                                                                             // set the allAND variable to false.
        }
        if (queryoperators[i]=="AND") {                                                                               // If the operator is AND...
          allOR = false;                                                                                              // set the allOR variable to false.
        }                                                                                                                                               
      }                                                                            

      if (queryoperators.length==0){                                                                                  // If there are no operators...
        allAND = false;                                                                                               // set allAND to false.
        allOR = false;                                                                                                // set allOR to false.
      }

      if (allAND == true){                                                                                            // If all the operators are AND...

        for (var i = 0; i <queryterms.length; i++){                                                                   // For each term (i),
          for (var j = 0; j<queryterms.length; j++){                                                                  // iterate through each term again (j)...
            if (i+j) {(jsonlinks +=(","))};                                                                           // If past the first set (i[0],j[0]) of terms, add a comma.
            jsonlinks += ("\n\t\t{\"source\": \"" + queryterms[i] + "\", \"target\":\"" + queryterms[j] + "\"}");     // Add i and j terms to jsonlinks text. 
          }                                                                                                           // Done for each of j terms.
        }                                                                                                             // Done for each of i terms.
      }                                                                                                               // Done the if statement that applies to allAND queries.

      else if (allOR == true){                                                                                         // If all the operators are OR...
        // do nothing because there are no source/target links                                                         // do nothing because there are no source/target links for json.
      }

      else {                                                                                                           // If there is some combination of operators, this gets tricky. Need to use parentheses.
        // for (var i = 0; i <queryoperators.length; i++){                                                             // boolean-parser package???
        //   if (i) {(jsonlinks +=(","))};                                                                             //  
        //   if (queryoperators[i]=="AND"){                                                                            //
        //     jsonlinks += ("\n\t\t{\"source\": \"" + queryterms[i] + "\", \"target\":\"" + queryterms[i+1] + "\"}"); //
        //   }                                                                                                         //
        //   if (queryoperators[i]=="OR"){                                                                             //
        //   }                                                                                                         //
        // }                                                                                                           //
      }                                                                                                                //

      jsontext = "{\n\t\"nodes\": [" + jsonnodes + "\n\t]," + "\n\n\t\"links\": [" + jsonlinks + "\n\t]\n}";           // Create the json text!
      sessionStorage.setItem("jsontext", jsontext);                                                              //
      jsontext = sessionStorage.getItem("jsontext");
                                                                                                 // Function returns jsontext when called.
    };                                                                                                                 // Done parsequery function.

                                                                                                                       // d3 stuff
var svg = d3.select("svg");                                                                                            //

var graph = JSON.parse(jsontext);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);                                                                      //

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()                                                                                  //
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))                                                    //
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-4000))                                                               //
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(+svg.attr("width")/2, +svg.attr("height")/2));                                     //

  var link = svg.append("g")                                                                                           //
      .attr("class", "links")                                                                                          //
    .selectAll("line")                                                                                                 //
    .data(graph.links)                                                                                                 //
    .enter().append("line")                                                                                            //
      .attr("stroke-width", 40)                                                                                        //
      .attr("stroke-linecap", 'round')                                                                                 //
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.value); })                                                          //

  var node = svg.append("g")                                                                                           //
      .attr("class", "nodes")                                                                                          //
    .selectAll("g")                                                                                                    //
    .data(graph.nodes)                                                                                                 //
    .enter().append("g")                                                                                               //

  var nodecircles = node.append("circle")                                                                              //
      .attr("r", 5)                                                                                                    //
      .attr("fill", 'black')                                                                                           //
      .call(d3.drag()                                                                                                  //
          .on("start", dragstarted)                                                                                    //
          .on("drag", dragged)                                                                                         //
          .on("end", dragended));                                                                                      //

  var nodelabels = node.append("text")                                                                                 //
      .text(function(d) {                                                                                              //
        return d.id;                                                                                                   //
      })
      .attr('x', 6)                                                                                                    //
      .attr('y', 3);                                                                                                   //

  node.append("title")                                                                                                 //
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });                                                                             //

  simulation                                                                                                           //
      .nodes(graph.nodes)                                                                                              //
      .on("tick", ticked);                                                                                             //

  simulation.force("link")                                                                                             //
      .links(graph.links);                                                                                             //

  function ticked() {                                                                                                  //
    link                                                                                                               //
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })                                                                //
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })                                                                //
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })                                                                //
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });                                                               //

    node                                                                                                               //
        .attr("transform", function(d) {                                                                               //
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";                                                                 //
        })                                                                                                             //
  }                                                                                                                    //

function dragstarted(d) {                                                                                              //
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();                                                         //
  d.fx = d.x;                                                                                                          //
  d.fy = d.y;                                                                                                          //
}

function dragged(d) {                                                                                                  //
  d.fx = d3.event.x;                                                                                                   //
  d.fy = d3.event.y;                                                                                                   //
}

function dragended(d) {                                                                                                //
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);                                                                     //
  d.fx = null;                                                                                                         //
  d.fy = null;                                                                                                         //
}                                                                                                                      //


</script>                                                                                                <!-- End of Javascript, for now. -->


<body>                                                                                                   <!-- Body here: -->

  <input type="text" id="querytext" placeholder="enter your query..."/>                                  <!-- Makes (enter your query...) text box. -->
  <button id ="button" onclick="parsequery()">parse!</button> <br />                                     <!-- Makes (visualize) button. -->      
  <p></p>                                                                                                <!-- Makes space (paragraph) after (visualize button). -->                  
  <span id="querytoprint"></span>                                                                        <!-- Print text (querytoprint is query from text box). -->

  <script>

                                                                                                         // Makes 'enter' function as buttonclick (i.e. run parsequery):
   document.getElementById("querytext").addEventListener("keyup", function(torunafterkeyup) {            // Listen to querytext for keyup, run function(torunafterkeyup).
      torunafterkeyup.preventDefault();                                                                  // Cancel default action of keyup, whatever this is.
      if (torunafterkeyup.keyCode === 13) {                                                              // If enter key is pressed...
        document.getElementById("button").click();                                                       // click "visualize" button.
      }})

  </script>                                                                                              <!-- Javascript ends here. -->

</body>                                                                                                  <!-- Body ends here. -->
```

Comment: Instead of making your graph variable a global to the page, store it in the sessionStorage after initializing it.

Comment: Are you storing a valid JSON String or an actual Javascript Object? If you are storing a string then you will have to convert it to an object first using var obj = JSON.parse('{json:"string"}')

Comment: The stored thing is: jsontext = "{\n\t\"nodes\": [" + jsonnodes + "\n\t]," + "\n\n\t\"links\": [" + jsonlinks + "\n\t]\n}"    I assume this is a valid JSON string, but I'm not sure... I'll try converting to an object, thanks a bunch!

Comment: When I try converting to an object, I get the following error: _Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>_   I think this is because the variable is "undefined", I'm not sure why... yet.

Comment: Are you building an object as the user enters data? How are you parsing information when it comes in? Could you edit your question to share the code for your parsequery() function?

Comment: Sure! I'll add the relevant bits of parsequery() to my question now.

Comment: I get: _Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1_ when I try to convert to an object (JSON.parse), so I assume it's already an object. But when I run without using JSON.parse, I get _Uncaught TypeError: svg.append(...).attr(...).selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function_... I'm confused because this part of the code works if I define jsontext right in the script, but doesn't seem to work if I'm using the variable from sessionStorage.

Comment: Or if I declare a string var jsontext = ' '; initially, then JSON.parse later, I get the following error _Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)_

Comment: I combined everything in one function to run on button press, solving the scope problem, whatever it was. I'd still be interested to know how to make the jsontext variable accessible outside a function, for future reference.